Completely remove Docker Desktop - still shows something Login Elements
I want to completely remove Docker Desktop from my macbook (M3, Sonoma) to perform a clean installation from scratch; I performed an uninstall using Appcleaner, but still I have something left on the Login Elements:

I even tried to use FAF (Find Any File), but I still have not found where should be... could it be related to:
\usr\share\vim\vim90\ftpplugin\dockerfile.vim
\usr\share\vim\vim90\syntax\dockerfile.vim
? how can I delete those files?

While Appcleaner is a decent method much of the time, sometimes apps have their own uninstaller for their own reasons. QtCreator is one example. Maybe try reinstalling, then uninstalling via the docker-provided method instead:

Another thing you could try is using Onyx to rebuild the launch database:

Back to Appcleaner, sometimes it doesn’t even check all associated files/folders by default. So make sure that they were all checked for deletion. By default, here's what it looks like with docker on my end.

And lastly, some updates to background service databases might be done during a simple restart.
